# XPath: Select Current and Next Node's text by Current Node Attributes

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

If this is a repeat question, I apologize, but I can't find another question either on SO or elsewhere that seems to handle what I need. Here is my question:

I'm using `scrapy` to get some information out of [this](http://www.utm.utoronto.ca/regcal/WEBLISTCOURSES1.html) webpage. For clarity, following is a block of the source code from that webpage, which is of interest to me:

```
<p class="titlestyle">ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology 
                        <span class='distribution'>(SCI)</span></p> 

<span class='normaltext'> 
Anthropology is the global and holistic study of human biology and behaviour, and includes four subfields: biological anthropology, archaeology, sociocultural anthropology and linguistics. The material covered is  directed  to answering the question: What makes us human? This course is a survey of  biological  anthropology and  archaeology.  [<span class='Helpcourse'
            onMouseover="showtip(this,event,'24 Lectures')"
            onMouseout="hidetip()">24L</span>, <span class='Helpcourse'
            onMouseover="showtip(this,event,'12 Tutorials')"
            onMouseout="hidetip()">12T</span>]<br> 

<span class='title2'>Exclusion: </span><a href='javascript:OpenCourse("WEBCOURSENOTFOUND.html")'>ANT100Y5</a><br>

<span class='title2'>Prerequisite: </span><a href='javascript:OpenCourse("WEBCOURSEANT102H5.pl?fv=1")'>ANT102H5</a><br> 
</span><br/><br/<br/>
```

Almost all of the code on that page looks like the above block.

From all of this, I need to grab:

1. ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology
2. Exclusion: ANT100Y5
3. Prerequisite: ANT102H5

The problem is that `Exclusion:` is inside a `<span class="title2">` and `ANT100Y5` is inside the following `<a>`.

I don't seem to be able to grab both of them out of this source code. Currently, I have code that attempts (and fails) to grab `ANT100Y5` which looks like:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select("//*[(name() = 'p' and @class = 'titlestyle') or (name() = 'a' and @href and preceding-sibling::'//span/@class=title2')]")
```

I'd appreciate any help with this, even if it's a "you're blind for not seeing this other SO question which answers this perfectly" (in which case,  myself will vote to close this). I really am that much at my wits end.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: Complete original code after changes suggested by @Dimitre**

I'm using the following code:

```
class regcalSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "disc"
    allowed_domains = ['www.utm.utoronto.ca']
    start_urls = ['http://www.utm.utoronto.ca/regcal/WEBLISTCOURSES1.html']

    def parse(self, response):
            items = []
            hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
            sites = hxs.select("/*/p/text()[1] | \
                              (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/text() | \
                              (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/following-sibling::a[1]/text() | \
                              (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/text() | \
                              (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()")

            for site in sites:
                    item = RegcalItem()
                    item['title'] = site.select("a/text()").extract()
                    item['link'] = site.select("a/@href").extract()
                    item['desc'] = site.select("text()").extract()
                    items.append(item)
            return items

            filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
            open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Which gives me this result:

```
[{"title": [], "link": [], "desc": []},
 {"title": [], "link": [], "desc": []},
 {"title": [], "link": [], "desc": []}]
```

This is not the output that I need. What am I doing wrong? Keep in mind that I'm running this script on [this](http://www.utm.utoronto.ca/regcal/WEBLISTCOURSES1.html), as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My answers are quite like those of @Flack**:

Having this XML document (corrected the provided one in closing numerous unclosed `<br>`s and in wrapping everything in a single top element):

```
<body>
    <p class="titlestyle">ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology 
        <span class='distribution'>(SCI)</span>
    </p>
    <span class='normaltext'> Anthropology is the global and holistic study of human biology and behaviour, and includes four subfields: biological anthropology, archaeology, sociocultural anthropology and linguistics. The material covered is directed to answering the question: What makes us human? This course is a survey of biological anthropology and archaeology. [
        <span class='Helpcourse' onMouseover="showtip(this,event,'24 Lectures')" onMouseout="hidetip()">24L</span>, 
        <span class='Helpcourse' onMouseover="showtip(this,event,'12 Tutorials')" onMouseout="hidetip()">12T</span>]
        <br/>
        <span class='title2'>Exclusion: </span>
        <a href='javascript:OpenCourse("WEBCOURSENOTFOUND.html")'>ANT100Y5</a>
        <br/>
        <span class='title2'>Prerequisite: </span>
        <a href='javascript:OpenCourse("WEBCOURSEANT102H5.pl?fv=1")'>ANT102H5</a>
        <br/>
    </span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</body>
```

**This XPath expression**:

```
normalize-space(/*/p/text()[1])
```

when evaluated produces the wanted string (the surrounding quotes are not in the result. I added them to show the exact string produced):

```
"ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology"
```

**This XPath expression**:

```
concat((//span[@class='title2'])[1],
            (//span[@class='title2'])[1]
                   /following-sibling::a[1]
            )
```

when evaluated produces the following wanted result:

```
"Exclusion: ANT100Y5"
```

**This XPath expression**:

```
concat((//span[@class='title2'])[2],
            (//span[@class='title2'])[2]
                   /following-sibling::a[1]
            )
```

when evaluated produces the following wanted result:

```
"Prerequisite: ANT102H5"
```

**Note**: In this particular case the abbreviation `//` is not needed and in fact this abbreviation should always when possible be avoided, because it leads to slower evaluation of the expression, causing in many cases a complete (sub) tree traversal. I am using '//' intentionally, because the provided XML fragment doesn't give us the full structure of the XML document. Also, This demonstrates how to correctly index the results of using `//` (note the surrounding brackets) -- helping to prevent a very frequent mistake in trying to do so

**UPDATE**: The OP has requested a single XPath expression that selects all the required text nodes -- here it is:

```
/*/p/text()[1]
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
```

When applied on the same XML document as above, the concatenation of the text nodes is exactly what is required:

```
ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology          
        Exclusion: ANT100Y5Prerequisite: ANT102H5
```

**This result can be confirmed by running the following XSLT transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/p/text()[1]
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[1]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/text()
   |
    (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (specified previously in this answer), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology          
        Exclusion: ANT100Y5Prerequisite: ANT102H5
```

**Finally**: The following single XPath expression selects exactly all wanted text node in the HTML page, with the provided link (after tidying it to become well-formed XML):

```
  (//p[@class='titlestyle'])[2]/text()[1]
|
  (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/text()
|
  (//span[@class='title2'])[2]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
|
  (//span[@class='title2'])[3]/text()
|
  (//span[@class='title2'])[3]/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
```

Comment: I get how these work individually, but how can I write ONE xpath select statement that gets all three? Sorry for asking such a basic question, but this is my first foray into xpath..

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Simpy use the `concat()` function to get all these strings concatenated as a single string: `concat(ExprA, ExprB, ExprC)`

Comment: @Dimitre: But how does xpath differentiate between ExprA, ExprB and ExprC if they are all concatenated into one string?

Comment: @Dimitre: I've been trying to make your code work. But I keep getting syntax errors. So I copy-pasted your solution and I still get the following syntax error: normalize-space(/*/p/text()[1]), SyntaxError: invalid syntax. There is also an arrow pointing to the first '/' in "/*/p". Could you please explain why this won't work?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: If you want the three strings separately, then you just use the three expressions from my solution. If you want the text nodes, then you do not use any `concat()` function or the `normalize-space()` function and you must use the `|` operator between all subexpressions that select an individual node.

Comment: @Dimitre: I tried you last suggestion with no luck. I've posted the new code and the error message. Please help

Comment: @Dimitre: I was able to make the code syntactically legal (working code posted), but it doesn't do what you say it does (input/output posted in the OP). I'd appreciate any help

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I updated my answer (at the very end) with the requested single XPath expression. Please, do ask if there is still something unclear. :)

Comment: @Dimitre: Still no luck (latest code/results posted on the OP). Thanks so much for helping, but it seems I must ask for your help yet again... Am I doing something wrong with the very basics (like where the double-quotes go, etc?)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Maybe your XPath engine is non-compliant (less likely) or you are evaluationg the expression against different-ly structured XML document (more likely). If you evaluate the expression against the XPath document I am using in my answer (because you only provided an XML fragment), then you must get the same results as I get. I will include an XSLT transformation that shows what the evaluation result is.

Comment: @Dimitre: I'm evaluating it on a page that has blocks of that structure. I have linked [the page](http://www.utm.utoronto.ca/regcal/WEBLISTCOURSES1.html) in the OP.

Comment: @Dimitre: I have a feeling that other parts of my code my also be screwing up, therefore, I'm going to post the entire code on the OP

Comment: @inspectorG4dget:  I edited again my answer and provided a single XPath expression that selects all the required text nodes from the HTML page.

Comment: @Dimitre: Thank you, but this only grabs the first course's information. How do I make it grab the information for all courses from that page?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: You have asked much more questions than 1. Please, think well how to define your next problem and ask it in a new question (let me know via a comment when you've done that).

Comment: @Dimitre: The question has been reworded and posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208843/xpath-select-current-and-next-nodes-text-by-current-node-attributes). Please let me know if there's something that doesn't make sense to you and I will try to clarify it as soon as possible. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> .1. ANT101H5 Introduction to Biological Anthropology and Archaeology

```
p[@class='titlestyle']/text()
```

> .2. Exclusion: ANT100Y5

```
concat(
    span/span[@class='title2'][1],
    span/span[@class='title2'][1]/following-sibling::a[1]
    )
```

> .3. Prerequisite: ANT102H5

```
concat(
    span/span[@class='title2'][2],
    span/span[@class='title2'][2]/following-sibling::a[1]
    )
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer. I'm accepting Dimitre's answer over yours, if only for the additional explanation, which I need and appreciate. If I could accept two answers, I'd accept this one, too

Answer (score 2):

It's not difficult to select the three nodes you refer to (using techniques such as those of Flack). What's difficult is (a) selecting them without also selecting other things that you don't want, and (b) making your selection robust enough that it still selects them if the input is slightly different. We have to assume that you don't know exactly what's in the input - if you did, you wouldn't need to write an XPath expression to find out.

You've told us three things that you want to grab. But what are your criteria for selecting these three things, and not selecting something else? How much is known about what you are looking for?

You've expressed your problem as an XPath problem, but I would tackle it differently. I would start by transforming the input you have shown to something with better structure, using XSLT. In particular, I would try to wrap all the sibling elements that aren't within a `<p>` element into `<p>` elements, treating each group of successive elements ending in `<br>` as a paragraph. That can be done without too much difficulty using the `<xsl:for-each-group group-ending-with>` construct in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I could do something like that. But I'd really rather not. Also, I know that the webpage is structured exactly the way I've shown it. I want to use xpath because it is simpler than all the other parsing techniques I know. If you think I should use something else, I am not opposed to learning it, although I /have. been working on this project for a while and this is the last piece and I don't want to prolong it much further.